# How to modulate spreaded signal?

Tags: unetstack

I am trying to write a modulation function, referring below [function](https://blog.unetstack.net/custom-phy). I am not electrical engineer and doesn't know much about signal processing.

```java
private final int SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL = 150
private final float NFREQ = 1/15

private float[] bytes2signal(byte[] buf) {
  float[] signal = new float[buf.length * 8 * SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL * 2]   // 8 bits/byte, 2 floats/sample
  int p = 0
  for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      int bit = (buf[i] >> j) & 0x01
      float f = bit == 1 ? -NFREQ : NFREQ
      for (int k = 0; k < SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL; k++) {
        signal[p++] = (float)Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * f * k)
        signal[p++] = (float)Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * f * k)
      }
    }
  }
  return signal
}
```

But My buffer signal is actually having non-binary data (which is spreaded signal) i.e first element of my buf array is `-1,0,0,-1,0,1,1,0`

How can i modulate my spreaded signal using this modulation function ? I am little confuse about what is going on in the `for` loop.

To better understand this, I have statically converted data, Refer below.

```java
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        //JAVA BYTE ARRAY DECLARATION
        byte Bytesdata[];
        //MEMORY ALLOCATION FOR JAVA BYTE ARRAY
        Bytesdata = new byte[4];
        //ASSIGNING ELEMENTS TO JAVA BYTE ARRAY
        Bytesdata[0] = 20;
        Bytesdata[1] = 10;
        Bytesdata[2] = 30;
        Bytesdata[3] = 5;
        //BYTE ARRAY OUTPUT
        int sourcestation = 2;
        int[][] wtable = new int[][]{
          { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
          { 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1},
          { -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1},
          { 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1},
          { 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1},
          { 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1},
          { -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1},
          { 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1},
        };
       
        int[][] results = new int[wtable.length][wtable[0].length];
        int pos = 0;
        System.out.println(Bytesdata.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < Bytesdata.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Bytesdata[i]);
            System.out.println("Binary is " + (Integer.toBinaryString(Bytesdata[i])) );
            System.out.println("Byte is " + getByte(Bytesdata[i]));
            int j = 0;
            while (j < wtable.length) {
                System.out.println("j: "+j);
                results[i][j] = wtable[sourcestation][j] * getBit(Bytesdata, pos);
                System.out.println("wtable["+sourcestation+"]["+j+"]: "+wtable[sourcestation][j]);
                System.out.println("Position: "+pos);
                System.out.println("Data Bit: "+getBit(Bytesdata, pos));
                System.out.println("Result: "+results[i][j]);
                System.out.println("---------------------------");
                j+=1;
                pos+=1;
            }
            System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                System.out.print(results[i][j]+", ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        final int HDRSIZE = 5;
        final int SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL = 150;
        final float NFREQ = 1/15;
        float[] signal = new float[Bytesdata.length * 8 * SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL * 2];
        int p = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Bytesdata.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            int bit = (Bytesdata[i] >> j) & 0x01;
            float f = bit == 1 ? -NFREQ : NFREQ;
                for (int k = 0; k < SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL; k++) {
                signal[p++] = (float)Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * f * k);
                signal[p++] = (float)Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * f * k);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(signal);
        // System.out.println("Binary is " + (Integer.toBinaryString(signal)));
    
     }
     
   
    private static int getBit(byte[] data, int pos) {
      int posByte = pos/8;
      int posBit = pos%8;
      byte valByte = data[posByte];
      int valInt = valByte>>(8-(posBit+1)) & 0x0001;
      return valInt;
   }
   
   private static String getByte(Byte b){
      String temp = Integer.toBinaryString(b);
      while(temp.length() < 8){
          temp = "0" + temp;
      }
      return temp;
   }  
}
```

I think my **output** seems correct.

```sh
Hello World
4
20
Binary is 10100
Byte is 00010100
j: 0
wtable[2][0]: -1
Position: 0
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 1
wtable[2][1]: -1
Position: 1
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 2
wtable[2][2]: 1
Position: 2
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 3
wtable[2][3]: -1
Position: 3
Data Bit: 1
Result: -1
---------------------------
j: 4
wtable[2][4]: 1
Position: 4
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 5
wtable[2][5]: -1
Position: 5
Data Bit: 1
Result: -1
---------------------------
j: 6
wtable[2][6]: -1
Position: 6
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 7
wtable[2][7]: 1
Position: 7
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
10
Binary is 1010
Byte is 00001010
j: 0
wtable[2][0]: -1
Position: 8
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 1
wtable[2][1]: -1
Position: 9
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 2
wtable[2][2]: 1
Position: 10
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 3
wtable[2][3]: -1
Position: 11
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 4
wtable[2][4]: 1
Position: 12
Data Bit: 1
Result: 1
---------------------------
j: 5
wtable[2][5]: -1
Position: 13
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 6
wtable[2][6]: -1
Position: 14
Data Bit: 1
Result: -1
---------------------------
j: 7
wtable[2][7]: 1
Position: 15
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
30
Binary is 11110
Byte is 00011110
j: 0
wtable[2][0]: -1
Position: 16
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 1
wtable[2][1]: -1
Position: 17
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 2
wtable[2][2]: 1
Position: 18
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 3
wtable[2][3]: -1
Position: 19
Data Bit: 1
Result: -1
---------------------------
j: 4
wtable[2][4]: 1
Position: 20
Data Bit: 1
Result: 1
---------------------------
j: 5
wtable[2][5]: -1
Position: 21
Data Bit: 1
Result: -1
---------------------------
j: 6
wtable[2][6]: -1
Position: 22
Data Bit: 1
Result: -1
---------------------------
j: 7
wtable[2][7]: 1
Position: 23
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
5
Binary is 101
Byte is 00000101
j: 0
wtable[2][0]: -1
Position: 24
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 1
wtable[2][1]: -1
Position: 25
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 2
wtable[2][2]: 1
Position: 26
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 3
wtable[2][3]: -1
Position: 27
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 4
wtable[2][4]: 1
Position: 28
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 5
wtable[2][5]: -1
Position: 29
Data Bit: 1
Result: -1
---------------------------
j: 6
wtable[2][6]: -1
Position: 30
Data Bit: 0
Result: 0
---------------------------
j: 7
wtable[2][7]: 1
Position: 31
Data Bit: 1
Result: 1
---------------------------
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
[F@6d06d69c
```

In the original `modulation` function, There is the decision made based on `1 or 0`. How can i modulate my signal ?

```
0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

Am i doing something wrong ? How can i dynamically do multiplication for `element-by-element` ?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet for `bytes2signal()` that you have here takes in binary data (bits `0` and `1`) and encodes them using two distinct frequencies (`NFREQ` for bit `0`, and `-NFREQ` for bit `1`). This modulation is called a binary frequency shift keying (BFSK), and is a mapping from bits to frequency.

FSK can deal with non-binary data if you like (e.g. you could have 2 bits mapped to one frequency: `00` => `f1`, `01` => `f2`, `10` => `f3` and `11` => `f4`, for some frequencies `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, and `f4`). In your example, you seem to have an input data sequence drawn from the alphabet {`0`, `1`, `-1`}, and so you could easily map each value to one of 3 frequencies (e.g. `-1` => `-FREQ`, `0` => `0`, `+1` => `+FREQ`).

However, it isn't clear to me that this is really what you intend. You mention "spread signal", and so I'm guessing you are looking to do spread spectrum communications?

If so, for BFSK, the "standard" way to do spread spectrum is to hop through frequencies, still selecting one of two frequencies based on bits 0 and 1, but changing which two frequencies as a function of time. This is called frequency-hopping BFSK (FH-BFSK). If you go this approach, the input sequence is still binary; all you change is replace `-NFREQ` and `FREQ` with two frequencies from a lookup table of frequencies that cycle through time.

Another common way to do spread spectrum communication is to use a spreading code to expand each bit into a sequence of bits (e.g. `0` => `1001`, and `1` => `1010`), with the requirement that the sequences are orthogonal. The "spreaded" bits are then modulated at a higher signaling rate (in your example above, by increasing `SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL` by a factor of 4, and by increasing `NFREQ` by a factor of 4 to accommodate the increased bandwidth). This is called direct sequence spread spectrum (DSSS), and is typically used in systems such as [CDMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-division_multiple_access). However, do note that the "spreaded" bit sequence is still binary (and does not have 3 levels {`-1`, `0`, `+1`} like you have in your question).

Note though that DSSS is more commonly used with binary phase-shift keying (BPSK) rather than with BFSK.